# Obtengo puntos negativos, pero no me muestra en el listado de logros que alguien lo asignó

Tags: bug, soporte, reputación, votos

He notado en demasiadas ocasiones y en varias etiquetas que de repente obtengo -1, pues paso de tener 10 de reputación a 8.

**Lo extraño es que no me muestra que alguien me asignó el -1 en el listado de logros.**

¿Alguien sabe la razón por la cual no aparece?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Atención**:

NO pregunto por qué me votan negativo, ni el por qué de los votos, ni tampoco cuándo se hace uso del negativo, **mi pregunta es saber por qué no se reportan en la pantalla de logros, pues esperaría ver un -2**. ¿Puede que sea un bug?

Comment: De usuario a usuario, fuera del asunto de moderación: yo voto en contra cuando veo preguntas/respuestas que me parecen que no ayudan, de la misma manera que voto a favor cuando encuentro preguntas/respuestas que me parecen que aportan a la comunidad, sobretodo en el tag Java. Y sí, yo voto varias veces en contra a múltiples usuarios, entre ellos tú. No es un misterio, solo es uso de la plataforma.

Comment: Creo a Elenasys NO esta preguntado por que le votan -1, ni el por que de los votos, ni tampoco cuando se hace uso del -1, creo que lo que pregunta es por que no se le comunica de la misma manera que cuando consigue +1 ect. Saludos

Comment: @Elenasys *El clavo que sobresale se lleva más golpes* | quizas tengas trolls. Saludos

Comment: Yo creo que eso es para evitar conflictos entre usuarios

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué es lo que ves exactamente en el listado de logros, un +8 que sabes que corresponde a un voto positivo y uno negativo? ¿O alguna otra cosa?

Comment: A mi tambien me ha pasado en alguna respuesta que he dado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto sucede, cuando los votos positivos/negativos están muy cerca en el tiempo y entonces en el *timeline* resumen aparece así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí otro caso, una pregunta tiene +46 pero nunca se muestran los -2 :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me extraña muchísimo lo que comentas y nunca he visto nada similar referido en ninguna de las Metas de todos los sitios que frecuento (que son muchos). Probablemente tiene que ver con [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/209901), que está en status-declined.

Comment: Hola Elenasys. La verdad Me extraña mucho lo que comentas... quieres hablarlo en un chat privado?

Comment: Buen día compañeros, agregué una imagen, si @MiquelColl con gusto.

Comment: A mí me sigue pareciendo normal: se agrupan los votos de manera que igual que enseña +30 por _Changing ImageView source_ (3 votos postivos), +10 por _Depura muy detallado_ (1 voto positivo) y +8 por _Tengo una clase..._ (1 voto positivo / 1 voto negativo). Al fin y al cabo solamente está agrupando la reputación ganada a través de cada una de las publicaciones.

Comment: A mí en stackoverflow en inglés si que se me muestran los votos negativos por separado. Sin embargo, en Stackoverflow en español, no así que entiendo que es un bug de este sitio.

Comment: El segundo caso que comentas es completamente distinto. En este caso no recibiste votos negativos, sino que llegaste al límite de 200 puntos diarios vía votos y no pudiste sumar más. Mira en http://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation para auditar los datos. Con toda seguridad verás algún voto de la forma [6], pues antes de recibir ese voto estabas en 194 y solo podías sumar +6. Mirando en http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/elenasys?tab=reputation se confirma.

Answer (score 6):

> Lo extraño es que no me muestra que alguien me asigno el -1 en el
>   listado de logros.

Creo entender lo que usted pregunta, esperarias algo como lo siguiente para una respuesta de -1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solo ves los logros positivos y otras cosas como pueden ser medallas ect.

Es buena pregunta, le dejo mi conjetura y es que creo que solo se muestran lo que se consideran logros como tal, y creo que eso excluye a los -1, pues me imagino que el obtener los -1 no es considerado un logro.

Por otro lado usted puede consultarlos en su perfil -> actividad -> reputación.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/elenasys?tab=reputation

Puedes usar lo anterior para consultar algo y usar como guia, los cambios de reputacion que no terminen en `0` o `5` por ejemplo: `78`, `33`, `143`, aunque en algunos casos puede ser, por una edicion de `wiki-etiquetas` pues creo que se otorgar `+2` pero creo que asi es mas facil de consultar algo. Saludos

Comment: gracias Angel entendiste mi pregunta, tengo curiosidad porque en ocasiones no se reportan los negativos en logros ya que veo que se me asignaron un negativo pero no se reporta el -2, solo es curiosidad, tal vez un bug!

Answer (score 4):

Recién recibí un voto negativo en Web Applications. En el desplegable de logros me muestra -2. Si se tratara de un bug podría ser específico Stack Overflow en español.

[image: Logros mostrando votos negativos]

Comment: Ruben, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, eso es exactamente lo que esperaría!, pero en ocasiones solo me muestra que la pregunta de tener por ejemplo 10, cambia a 8, pero no se despliega el -2 !!! =0 Probablemente es un bug en stackoverflow en español, aunque si he visto que se muestra el -2 pero en otras ocasiones no!

Comment: @Elenasys: Me parece que lo que está pasando es que cada hilo se muestra sólo una vez por grupo de fecha (Hoy, Ayer, Últimos 7 días...) y se muestran los datos agregados de todos los votos de un mismo hilo por cada grupo. Por ejemplo, en la imagen se muestra un hilo con +25  que es la agregación de +10 del voto positivo y +15 por aceptación de la respuesta.